# Python,BeautifulSoup4: select elements where multiple attributes equal multiple values respectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=700 border=0 617px; HEIGHT: 22px 23px 536px;>
    ...
</TABLE>
```

I want to select all the elements just like above:the tag is `TABLE`, and there are several attributes(`cellSpacing=0,cellPadding=0,width=700,border=0`).

I tried the following python script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result=requests.get("http://news.scu.edu.cn/news2012/cdzx/I0201index_1.htm")
result.encoding="GBK"
soup=BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
soup=soup.find("TABLE",attrs={"cellspacing":"0","cellpadding": "0","width": 
"700","border":"0"})
print(soup)
```

The script run without error,yet beautiful soup find nothing.This must be wrong,if you open the page(http://news.scu.edu.cn/news2012/cdzx/I0201index_1.htm) with Chrome,right click,go to inspect->Network->Doc->Response,search `<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=700 border=0 617px; HEIGHT: 22px 23px 536px;>`, you will find 30 matching results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TABLE` tag name has to be lower-cased:

```
soup = soup.find("table", ...)
```

Here is a [reference section in the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems):

> Because HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive, all three HTML parsers *convert tag and attribute names to lowercase*. That is, the markup `<TAG></TAG>` is converted to `<tag></tag>`.

Comment: Thanks,man!That's right,I changed "TABLE" to "table",finally beautiful soup returns some valid information.But there seems to be another problem:beautiful soup only return the 1st element of 30,do you have any idea what's the problem?

Comment: @bowen have you tried `find_all()` instead of `find()`?

Comment: Oops,sorry,I could have googled it.sorry man,I must have wasted your time.Thanks very much!!!